# Python REST API scraping keyError

Tags: python-3.x

I have Scraped a REST API, and here is my code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
import sqlite3
import datetime
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

url = "https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/20180125/BTC/USD"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

page = requests.get(url)
soup = soup(page.text, "html.parser")

a = soup("data1d")
```

I want the data of "data1d" from soup but when I try to do this it shows:

```
File "C:\Users\mubee\Downloads\Annaconda\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1011, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'data1d'
```

while there is a data present in "data1d" in variable soup. How can I get the data present in "data1d" only, from the variable soup?

Answer (score 0):

As the page is just json it is simple, no need for soup:

```
import requests
url = "https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/20180125/BTC/USD"

page = requests.get(url)
page_dict=page.json()

print(page_dict['data1d'])
```